# Magento 2 Unit Test error: Call to a member function getBaseUrl() on null

Tags: magento2, php-7, unit-tests, phpunit

I am looking to write basic unit tests for some helper functions that I am working on for a Magento 2 module. I am able to execute my custom module unit tests but I am getting the following error for the first test.

When I execute the tests for my module I get the following error:

> Call to a member function getBaseUrl() on null

My Helper code is below: I will be adding quite a few functions to it later and the function its self returns the correct result if I call it else where in my code, I am not able to get the test working.

```
namespace MyModuleSpace\MyModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {

    /**
     * Attribute to hold storeManager Object
     *
     * @var object
     */
    protected  $storeManager;

    /**
     * _construct
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * No params needed. Returns base site URL.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseURL() {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

}
```

My Unit Test code is

```
namespace MyModuleSpace\MyModule\Test\Unit\Helper;

//class HelperTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase { // not usable as it is not supported
class HelperTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {

    protected $helper;

    /**
     * Sets up the Mock (reflection) objects and properties for tests...
     *
     */
    protected function setUp() {

        $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
        $this->helper = $objectManager->getObject('MyModuleSpace\MyModule\Helper\Data');

    }

    /**
     * Run unit tests for getBaseURL()
     */
    public function testGetBaseURL() {

        $baseUrl = $this->helper->getBaseUrl();

        // Test we are returning a string...
        $this->assertTrue(is_string($baseUrl));

    }


}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you found a solution?, If yes, can you please tell me how.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It's bad practise to use ObjecManager, so thats should be improved first. Use your construct to instantiate the classes that you need, including the helper.

Comment: I agree, I have found a better approach, just got to figure out how to close this question. Followed a bad example from some research I had...

Comment: To close a question, you can simply accept an answer.

Comment: Use of this object manager in unit tests is totally acceptable

Comment: as @Shapeshifter said there is not need to inject classes with a constructor in unit tests and your are not answering his question